# I can not save bitmap to file

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Where are may mistake of this code. I can save the file with embacadero.delphi.firemonkey

```
  if FileExists(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine
    (System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 
    'MYIMG' +FormatDateTime('YYMMDD-HHMMSS', Now) + '.bmp')) then
    ShowMessage('Existed')
  else
    Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(
      System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath,
      'MYIMG' + FormatDateTime('YYMMDD-HHMMSS', Now) +'.bmp'));
```

After run this line of code there is nothing found in document directory of android OS.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken .bmp is not available on Android. Stick to jpg or png.

Comment: I have also changed the extension from .BMP to .JPG but it's not work.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with .PNG? Does your app have permissions to write to the user's documents folder?